# Virtualization: having hypervisor and VMX/EPT same time

Tags: virtualization

Recently, I updated to Win10 2018 April Update (1803 build) and stumbled at a virtualization modes thing.

**Intro:**

If you run `coreinfo -v` command you should see 3 lines:

- HYPERVISOR
- VMX
- EPT

**Situation:**

Before the update, I had first virtualization mode (hyphervisor) as ON and others as OFF (and had never bothered about). After I updated with 1803 build, I noticed I lost ability to start Win10 Mobile emulators and then figured out now I have first mode OFF and others ON.

**Question:**

Is there any hope to have all three virtualization modes ON same time? Or it's not possible technically?

P.S. `coreinfo` is an utility written by Mark Russinovich, freely available at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/coreinfo

Comment: Is Hyper-V installed? I think that would enable HYPERVISOR and set it to on.

Comment: Yes, it was installed, and still installed. The only change is virtualization modes on/off setup.

Answer (score 0):

Not actually an answer, but workaround at least:

1. Update to Win10 April 2018 update (version 1803)
2. Make sure you have "Hyper-V" feature installed
3. Make sure you have "Windows Hypervisor Platform" feature installed
4. Set virtualization mode to HYPERVISOR (run `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto` and then reboot)

That way, it seems hypervisor is able to emulate VMX/EPT behavior to guest machines. At least, now I can run simultaneously

- Visual Studio with Win10 Mobile/HoloLens emulator
- Android Studio with Android emulator
- Docker

Hope this could help somebody